# Android Google Place API, Drawing polyline

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to add polyline using google direction api. I'm getting two routes in the map instead of one route like in my screenshot image.

Please see the image. This is my code. 
I have followed one tutorial and doing same like in kotlin.

```
val link = "${DirectionUtils.DIRECTION_API}origin=${fromLatLng.latitude}," + "${fromLatLng.longitude}&destination=${toLatLng.latitude},${toLatLng.longitude}" + "&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=false&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&key=${resources.getString(
                        R.string.google_map_api
                    )}"
```

This is my code doing api call

```
APIClient(this).get(link, object : ResponseListener { override fun onResponse(statusCode: Int, response: String) { when (statusCode) {200 -> { val jsonObject: JSONObject = JSONObject(response)
                        Single.just(DecodePolyline().parse(jsonObject)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer<List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

                                it?.let {
                                    var points = ArrayList<LatLng>();


                                    for (i in 0 until it.size) {
                                        val path = it.get(i)

                                        for (j in 0 until path.size) {
                                            val point = path.get(j) as HashMap<String, String>

                                            try {
                                                val lat = point.get("lat")!!.toDouble();
                                                val lng = point.get("lng")!!.toDouble();
                                                val gottenLatLng = LatLng(lat, lng)
                                                points.add(gottenLatLng);

                                            } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                                                e.printStackTrace()
                                            }
                                        }
                                        points.addAll(points);
                                    }

                                    val lineOptions = PolylineOptions().width(5f)
                                        .color(resources.getColor(R.color.makerIconColor)).geodesic(true);
                                    for (i in 0 until points.size) {
                                        lineOptions.add(points.get(i))
                                    }
                                    mMap?.addPolyline(lineOptions)


                                    /* val greyOptions = PolylineOptions();
                                     greyOptions.width(10f);
                                     greyOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                                     greyOptions.startCap(SquareCap());
                                     greyOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND)
                                     greyOptions.endCap(SquareCap());
                                     placeHolderGoogleMapPolyline = this@run.addPolyline(greyOptions);
                                    */


                                    val width = resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                                    val height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                                    val padding = (width * 0.30).toInt()
                                    val latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
                                    latLngBounds.include(fromLatLng)
                                    latLngBounds.include(toLatLng)


                                    val cameraposition = CameraPosition.builder().zoom(17f)
                                        .target(latLngBounds.build().center).build()
                                    mMap?.animateCamera(
                                        CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraposition),
                                        1200, null
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    else -> {
                    }
                }
            }
        })
Decode Polyline related code in java

    public List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        return routes;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what you want, I think your code is correct, I think you need to change the color of the next routes to see the different routes

Comment: I just want only one route like other cab apps ola and uber does.